# show alert message on comparing time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have created a time drop down and its a 24 hour clock, i want to check the user selected time in drop down with the current system time which used 12 hour clock and show an alert if user selects the past time. How can i convert 24 hours clock to 12 hour and check the condition if user has selected a past time or not. Please suggest.

Below is the javascrpt function :

```
function showAlert(){
     var timeTextO = document.getElementById("time").value ; //if user selects 01:30, it displays 13:30 as its 24hour clock

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10){
       minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (hours < 10){
       hours = "0" + hours;
    }

    alert("currentTime " + currentTime);  //for example if current time is 01:30PM
    alert("hours " + hours); // 01
    alert('minutes ' + minutes);//30
    if(timeTextO < currentTime){
        alert("The Date and Time you have selected is before the Current Date and Time");
    } else {
        alert("same tme");
    }

  }
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `Date` objects contain a `getTime` function that returns the time in milliseconds as a number. You can compare two such numbers to easily compare the two `Date` objects.

```
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
if (d2.getTime() > d1.getTime()) {
    //d2 > d1! 
    //(also, we know this is true in this case because d2 was created after d1)
}
```

Comment: how can i implement getTime() for the user selected time, as i'm getting selected time using document.getElementById("time").value

Answer (score 0):

May this example enlighten you:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.toLocaleString("en");
        var dd = new Date(n);
        var nn = d.toLocaleString("de");
        alert(n + "---" + nn);
    }
</script>
```

So it is possible to pass Dates, formatted Dates back and forth.

And there is Date.getTime() showing us the millis since 1970. And they never lie :D

Comment: But how can i compare the date converted to milliseconds with the user selected date from dropdown?eg) in javascript function ,var timeTextO = document.getElementById("time").value ; //if user selects 01:30PM, it displays 13:30 as its 24hour clock

Comment: Problem is: timeTextO is a String. To compare it to a Date, you should bring timeTextO to a reasonable Date-String first, than construct a Date and compare it.